# payment method integration into sample payment gateway in magento2

Tags: magento2

Have integrated a sample payment gateway module into magento2.
Now I need to add some payment method in JS into a sample payment module. 
so that when the user clicks on place an order a pop appears.

I have a module like app/code/Vendor/Module.

magento2\app\code\Iostpay\Iostpaymagento\Model
 magento2
\app\code\Iostpay\Iostpaymagento\view

Comment: Can you put you extension in your question?

Comment: module path added

Comment: I need to check code

Comment: I have created a sample module first and placed it in app/code.
Now the main thing is I need to call JS function on click of place order if I select my payment gateway.
How do I call the php code with ajax?
Where should i keep the php file in a module or in view folder

Comment: You can put here /view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/simple.js

Comment: You can check this link https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-payment-method/

Comment: Thanks, I am checking this.